# Show that $f^T$ is measurable

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Suppose that $F \in~L^{+}$. Show that

$$
F^T =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }f(x)\le 1, \\[3pt]
f(x) & \text{if }1<f(x) <2, \\[3pt]
2 & \text{if }f(x)\ge 2,
\end{cases}
$$
is measurable.

I'm pretty sure I'm entirely lost on this. My only thoughts on this is to consider an open interval E (namely (1,2)) so there exists a function g(x) such that $$\int|g(x)-\chi_{E}(x)| \, dx<\epsilon$$ and $\int\chi_E \, dx= (2-1)$ and from here I'm lost.

Comment: Are $f$ and $F$ the same function? Otherwise the assumption $F \in L^+$ does not make much sense. If that is the case, I would think that just following the definition of “measurable” (together with a case analysis) should suffice to solve this problem (i.e. no need for integrals).

Comment: @EikeSchulte I want to say yes but I'm not really sure as to how this is going

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that $f$ and $F$ are meant to be same function. Also that $L^+$ is some space of functions that are in particular measurable (probably they are also at least non-negative and maybe summable, but we won’t need that).

To show that $f^T$ is measurable, we simply follow the definition of measurability: Denote by $X$ the domain of $f$. Let $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ be a measurable set. We have to show that $(f^T)^{-1}(A)$ is measurable. Now, \begin{align}
(f^T)^{-1}(A) 
  &= \{ x \in X \mid f^T(x) \in A \} \\
  &= \{ x \in X \mid \text{$f^T(x) \in A$ and ($f(x) \leq 1$ or $1 < f(x) < 2$ or $2 \leq f(x)$})\} \\
  &= \{ x \in X \mid f^T(x) \in A, f(x) \leq 1 \} \cup \{ x \in X \mid f^T(x) \in A, 1 < f(x) < 2 \} \\ &\qquad \cup \{ x \in X \mid f^T(x) \in A, 2 \leq f(x) \} \\
  &= \{ x \in X \mid 1 \in A, f(x) \leq 1 \} \cup \{ x \in X \mid f(x) \in A, 1 < f(x) < 2 \} \cup \{ x \in X \mid 2 \in A, 2 \leq f(x) \}.
\end{align} Notice that all of these sets are measurable by the measurability of $f$. Hence, their union is measurable.